# Load Black Chancery on Overleaf

Tags: fonts, overleaf

I'd like to load a new latex font, the **Black Chancery** on *Overleaf*. How must I do? Thank you so much

**First Edit:** I'm sorry, but I'm forced to return onto this problem. As **Sebastiano Molina** told me, I followed his promps in the comments below, and also the **Paolo Gessler**'s answer. What I did is this:

I searched in an italian site the *Blach Chancery* font, [HERE](https://www.dafont.com/it/search.php?text=Black%20Chancery&af=on&q=Black%20Chancery);

I loaded the **BLKCHCRY.TTF** onto XeLaTeX;

And I tried to compile the code below, but *Overleaf* gives me 5 ERRORS. Where did I wrong?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmathcal[
    Path = fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf
]{BLKCHCRY} %Here Overleaf gives me ERROR

\usepackage[upint]{stix}

\title{BLKCHCRY}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\LARGE

\section{Introduction}


\bigskip

% you need to be in math mode and use \mathfrak
\( \mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \)

\noindent This is regular text.

\end{document}
```

Thank you so much, again!

**Second Edit:** I add this: My goal is implement `tcolorbox, extarrows, ...`, many other packages and the **Black Chancery**-font on *Overleaf*. What Overleaf-mode I must use to implement all I need?

I'd like to precisize that the **Black Chancery**-font will not be my main font. But I'll use it only for a few things in mathmode!! Thankx again

**Third Edit:** I thank all you for answering me, but *Overleaf* still gives me 1 error, i.e.: **Package fontspec Error: The font "BLKCHCRY" cannot be found.** (see the code, row 10), as in this screenshot:

[image]

Where did I wrong? Thank you so much again!

Comment: (I'm on support staff at Overleaf.) We have instructions for this here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_have_a_custom_font_I%27d_like_to_load_to_my_document._How_can_I_do_this%3F If you've tried this and something didn't work, please post a complete example document of what you had tried, so we can take a closer look.

Comment: You have the font in a different path than the one you specified. You have it in `fonts/BLKCHCRY/` but your code expects it to be in `fonts/`. Either move the .ttf file into `fonts/` or edit `Path = fonts/,` to be `Path = fonts/BLKCHCRY/`. (But not both, of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a command `\BLKCHCRY` which you never defined, because you only set it as your main font.

You shouldn't set it as your main font if you only want to use it in math mode. You especially shouldn't set it as your main font and then load stix as your main font right afterwards.

(You might want to switch to use the .otf version of the stix fonts for XeLaTeX, but I don't know offhand if they're available on Overleaf, since I don't use Overleaf.)

If you only want to use it in math mode, you should use mathspec to set it as one of your math fonts: the mathcal or mathfrak fonts probably make the most sense.

Since mathtools loads amsmath, it needs to be loaded before mathspec.

You don't need `\inputenc` for XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{mathspec}

\usepackage[upint]{stix}

\setmathcal[
    Path = fonts/,
    Extension = .ttf
]{BLKCHCRY}

\title{BLKCHCRY}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\bigskip

% you need to be in math mode and use \mathfrak
\( \mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \)

\noindent This is regular text.

\end{document}
```

[image: black chancery]

Compile with XeLaTeX and make sure BLCKCHCRY.ttf is in the `fonts/` subfolder of your project.

You can use `\setmathfrak` with `\mathfrak` instead if you want to set it as the math fraktur font.

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I edited my question, adding a photo.

Comment: I was expecting that the file should be in `fonts/`. You have it in `fonts/BLKCHCRY/` instead. Either move the .ttf file into `fonts/` or edit `Path = fonts/,` to be `Path = fonts/BLKCHCRY/`. (But not both, of course.)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to change the compiler to XeLaTeX. Then, create a fonts folder in your Overleaf project and upload the font into the folder. Loading the `mathspec` library, you can put this on the preamble

```
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont[
    Path = fonts/ ,
    Extension = .ttf ,
]{BLKCHCRY}
```

Done.

Comment: Thanx, I'm using pdflatex. And I would not like to use xelatex. Is it enough to follow what written in the link that Paolo Gessler sended? Thanks again

Comment: @Puck - `Black Chancery` is an opentype font, and pdflatex just doesn't provide the capabilities needed to work natively with opentype fonts. That's why you're getting the advice to use XeLaTeX; by the way, LuaLaTeX will work as well.

Comment: @Sebastiano Molina: Your answer is not ok because XeLaTeX does not found **BLKCHCRY**. Futhermore XeLaTeX does not recognize some packages such as tcolorbox and extarrows.

Comment: By `BLKCHCRY` i meant that the font `.TTF`  was called `BLKCHCRY`.ttf` , as it was called when I downloaded it. If it is called `BlackChancery.ttf`, then you should put `BlackChancery` as the argument.

Comment: If you wanted to stick with pdflatex, [URW Chancery](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/urwchancery/) is available, though obviously it's not quite the same.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to set Black Chancery as your `\mathcal` font, with `unicode-math`.  You seem to want to use STIX Two for all other math.  (Warning: untested, but it should work in either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.)

This also scales the font to match the height of your other fonts.  Consider adding `Scale=MatchUppercase` to your `\setmathcal` command if you go with the `mathspec` solution, or your `\mathcal` symbols will be incongruously large.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
  StylisticSet=8 ] % Upright integrals
\setmathfont{BLKCHCRY}[
    range = cal,
    Scale = MatchUppercase,
    Path = fonts/,
    Extension = .TTF]

\title{BLKCHCRY}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}


\bigskip

% you need to be in math mode and use \mathfrak
\( \mathcal{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \)

\noindent This is regular text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok, it's good because it correctly works.